# How to get the information inside a canvas element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

so I'm trying to get some numbers that are inside a canvas element, i tryied to webscrapy it with bs4, but got nothing, so i have nothing relevant to show.

```
<div class="historyStatisticsGrid--86e15" data-interactive="true">
<canvas width="286" height="87" style="touch-action: manipulation; `width: 228.8px; height: 69.6px;"></canvas></div>`
```

the canvas look similar to this, if i can not scrap is there aniway that i can get that information(sorry for bad english).

Comment: This is not possible. In fact, it's very likely that the website you are trying to scrape has specifically implemented this method to prevent people doing exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Canvas data is CORS protected within the browser, you can access it with javascript on the page from the same site. Which is likely why they put the numbers in a canvas element. ... I suspect the Terms of Service for the site says no data mining; in any event the implementation is to stop data mining. And they may have additional coding such as blocking an IP address.

Comment: If you want to make a mobil application ... best practice is to tell them and ask for a API to access the data without needing the user to prove they are human. The credentials would be hidden in the app. But they may have a license to display the data and not have a license to distribute it to others.

Comment: What data are you trying to get exactly? "i tryied to webscrapy it with bs4, but got nothing, so i have nothing relevant to show" -- actually, it's still quite relevant (not to mention a site requirement--see [ask]). Oftentimes, it's only a simple tweak that makes your code work, and even if it isn't, seeing your attempt saves a lot of time for answerers and makes it much clearer what you're trying to accomplish by providing context. So please share your code as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @Besworks thanks, i'm a bit dissapointed, but thank for the your honesty